# How to allow file-access-from-files?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, getimagedata

I have been working through the HTML5 canvas tutorial(s). Currently on Pixel manipulation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas, and hit on a problem/issue.

The issue concerns canvas and getImageData() method. The work-around (when working with local files) seems to be to store and load the image from same directory as our HTML page. Not the most elegant solution, and I have similar issue with Google Chrome, but I am able to fix this in Chrome by launching app from Terminal and setting --args. The issue is not present in Safari, (all on OS X).

Is there a similar (or better) way of launching Firefox to allow 'file-acces-from-files' locally?

I hope this makes sense. Many thanks in anticipation.

-u

Comment: If you are working only locally, and your issue concerns only development you could download addons to make your life easier.
[Ex. Chrome addon.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

Alternativelly, you could send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but this appears to be a Chrome addon. The issue is with Firefox.

Comment: Having the users modify their browser settings is quite invasive (and maybe suspicious to them) unless you have a captured client base -- eg, if your app is a sanctioned corporate app. Alternatively, satisfying cross-domain security restrictions (and therefore getting access to `.getImageData`) requires that the user is involved in loading the file from their local file system. One way is to have the user load the image file with `input type=file`. Another way is to use have the user load the image file with `FileReader`. There are previous SO Q&A using both these alternatives.

Comment: AFAIK the cross domain issue occurs only when testing locally.

Comment: @ugajin CORS restrictions always apply. If the image file is located on the same domain as the web page, then CORS is satisfied. If the user affirmatively acquiesces to loading the image file, then CORS is satisfied. But violating the CORS restrictions (as opposed to satisfying CORS) will always result in a tainted canvas which prevents pixel manipulation ;-)

Comment: @ugajin I just gave an example. By seaching you should be able to find one for [Firefox](https://github.com/spenibus/cors-everywhere-firefox-addon) too.

Comment: Thanks, it all seems a bit too complex. For Chrome the fix was simple as I was able to run the following Terminal cmd: 'open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --allow-file-access-from-files'. Its not ideal, but it works, no more cross-origin issues, and it is better than having to change the directory tree/hierarchy, as I am currently doing for firefox. I was hoping there might be a similar 'fix' for Firefox.